# How to run tensorflow-gpu

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, anaconda, gpu

I have one problem, my jupyter Notebook does not run on the gpu. I updated my Driver (Nvidia GTX 1660 Ti), installed CUDA 11, put the CuDNN-files into the folders and put the correct path in the environmental variables.
After doing that, I added a new environment to Anaconda including a GPU-kernel and installed tensorflow-gpu (Version 2.4, because CUDA 11 needs Version >= 2.4.0), like it is explained in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPq6NIboLSc&t=204s&ab_channel=thehardwareguy).

After that I opened jupyter notebook with the new kernel. So I can run my code and until a certain step that works, but my GPU utilization in the task manager is below 1% and my RAM is at 60%-99%. So I think, my code isn't running on the GPU. I made a few tests:

```
import tensorflow.keras
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.__version__)
print(tensorflow.keras.__version__)

print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
print(tf.test.is_gpu_available())
```

leads to (What I think it is correct):

```
2.4.0
2.4.0
True
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
True
```

The next test is:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

What leads to:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 9334837591848971536
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 4837251481
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 2660164806064353779
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1660 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5"
]
```

So there is CPU and GPU in that kernel, isn't it?

What can I do, that my Neural Network is running on the GPU and not on the CPU?

My Code is running until I try to train my neural network. This is the code and the error occurring:

```
model.fit([np.asarray(X_train).astype(np.float32), np.asarray(X_train_zusatz).astype(np.float32)], 
          y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=10)
```

It is a concatenated neural network, if you are wondering about the input and it works quite fine with normal tensorflow (not tensorflow-gpu). But training need a very very long time.

```
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-10813edc74c8> in <module>
      3 
      4 model.fit([np.asarray(X_train).astype(np.float32), np.asarray(X_train_zusatz).astype(np.float32)], 
----> 5           y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=10)#, 
      6           #validation_data=[[X_test, X_test_zusatz], y_test], class_weight=class_weight)

~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-pac

kages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
       1098                 _r=1):
       1099               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
    -> 1100               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
       1101               if data_handler.should_sync:
       1102                 context.async_wait()
    
    ~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
        826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
        827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
    --> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
        829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
        830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    
    ~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
        886         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
        887         # stateless function.
    --> 888         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
        889     else:
        890       _, _, _, filtered_flat_args = \
    
    ~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       2941        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
       2942     return graph_function._call_flat(
    -> 2943         filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
       2944 
       2945   @property
    
    ~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
       1917       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
       1918       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
    -> 1919           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
       1920     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(
       1921         args,
    
    ~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
        558               inputs=args,
        559               attrs=attrs,
    --> 560               ctx=ctx)
        561         else:
        562           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(
    
    ~\.conda\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
         58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
         59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
    ---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
         61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
         62     if name is not None:
    
    ResourceExhaustedError: 2 root error(s) found.
      (0) Resource exhausted:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[300,300] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
         [[{{node model/lstm/while/body/_1/model/lstm/while/lstm_cell/split}}]]
    Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
    
         [[gradient_tape/model/embedding/embedding_lookup/Reshape/_74]]
    Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
    
      (1) Resource exhausted:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[300,300] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
         [[{{node model/lstm/while/body/_1/model/lstm/while/lstm_cell/split}}]]
    Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
    
    0 successful operations.
    0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_4691]
    
    Function call stack:
    train_function -> train_function
```

Why is this error occurring?

-Update-
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF05Y.jpg) is how my "nvidia-smi" looks like during training my model (After ca. 20 seconds of training).

Thank you and best regards,
Daniel

Comment: 1660ti has 6GB of memory or somwthing? And you probably use another 1Gb for your system to run. The scripts you published show that your gpu training runs all-right but is running out of memory. Try cutting out pieces of your model, decreasing layer sizes or number of neurons in layers, decreasing batch size, replacing optimizer with good old SGD, use gradient-checkpointing, place some layers on the CPU - some of it would help

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, 1660 ti has 6GB of memory. I decreased batch size to 10, and it still does not work. Decreasing layer sizes and changing optimizer to sgd leads to the same error. How can it be, that the program is working on the CPU (No error but slow) and on the GPU it is not working? The GPU should be faster, isn't it? I have a second graphic card (Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630), can that be the problem? But CUDA is installed to the nvidia graphic card automatically isn't it?

Comment: you can run nvidia-smi while running training to verify that nvidia gpu is used. Try setting batch-size to 1

Comment: running nvidia-smi you should expect nearly all of your 1660ti memory to be allocated by TF

Comment: Do I have to look at GPU-Util? If yes, it is 0%, the whole training. That means, the program is not running on the gpu? The graphic card has 1536 cores, maybe only one is used. Is that possible?

Comment: Run `watch nvida-smi` and see if `Memory-Usage` column changes much

Comment: Do you have any other program which is using gpu? Try closing that one.

Comment: I added a screenshot from my nvidia-smi during training (Added in the origin post at the bottom). I think it looks like, the program isn't using GPU, because GPU Memory Usage for python.exe is N/A. Additional, I have spotted a new hint: By creating the model, there is the warning: ``WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm will not use cuDNN kernel since it doesn't meet the cuDNN kernel criteria. It will use generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU``. I try another program later.

Comment: Trying another program leads to the same error.

Comment: pls check if you have the right `cudnn` version. Should be 8.x.x

Comment: ``cudnn`` has the right version (8.0.4). At the moment I think, that everything is working and the problem is the LSTM-layer. I found a few articles, where is described, that training on the GPU is very bad for recurrent layers. How do you think, is that possible? I am not sure, because in older versions, there is an extra layer (CuDNNLSTM), so training on the GPu has to work for LSTM too?

Comment: In Tensorflow, you can place operation to run on a device of your choice instead of what's automatically selected for you, you can use with `tf.device`. For more information please refer [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#manual_device_placement) site.Thanks!